# How can I display the return value of a function in a v-for loop in ionic vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ionic-framework

so I'm trying to display the return data that I get by calling the getUserData() function in the v-for part of the template. The data is correctly logged out, but not displayed. Does anyone have an idea what is happening here?

Thanks in Advance

This is my template:

```
<template>
  <ion-page>
    <NavBar/>
    <ion-content padding>
      {{currentuser.vorname}} haha
      <br/>
      Friends:
      <ion-list>
        <ion-item v-for="friend in this.currentuser.friends" :key="friend"> {{getUserData(friend)}} </ion-item>
      </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-page>
</template>
```

This is the function in question.

```
    getUserData: function(email){

      console.log(email);

      fetch("/getUserEntrybyEmail", {
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
          "Content-type" : "application/json"
        },
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify( { "email" : email } ),
      }).then(response=>{
        if(response.status==200){
        return response.json();}
        else{
          console.log("Access Denied.")
        }
      }).then((data)=>{

        console.log(data)
        return data;



      })
    }
```

Comment: I don't know anything about `ion` but looks like `getUserData` is returning `undefined`. if you were to `return fetch...` than this would return a promise, I would guess that you'd need to store the result of the fetch call and re-render your application somehow once this data is available. But again, I know nothing of this framework you are using.

Comment: When `/getUserEntrybyEmail` is successful. Does it return an array (a list of friends) or one entry like an object?

Comment: @SimoD'loMafuxwana

It returns a single Json

Comment: @Taer okay see answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update your logic a bit.

**Step 1**

- In your `data` add a friend property

```
  data() {
    return {
      friend: []
    }
  },
```

**Step 2**

- Handle the loop in your logic, not in the template.
- Fetch the data for each friend and add the result to the `friends` array
- Depending on your logic, this loop can be inside a method and that method can be called in `mounted()`

```
      for (let a = 0; this.currentuser.friends.length > a; a++) {
        const email = this.currentuser.friends[a].email;
        fetch("/getUserEntrybyEmail", {
          headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
            "Content-type" : "application/json"
          },
          method: "POST",
          body: JSON.stringify( { "email" : email } ),
        }).then(response => {
          if(response.status==200){
          return response.json();
          } else {
            console.log("Access Denied.")
          }
        }).then((data)=>{
          console.log(data)
    // add each result to the friends array
          this.friend.push(data);
        })
      }
```

Step 3
 - Update the template to use the `friends` array

```
<template>
  <ion-page>
    <NavBar/>
    <ion-content padding>
      {{currentuser.vorname}} haha
      <br/>
      Friends:
      <ion-list>
        <ion-item v-for="(friend, index) in friends" :key="index"> {{ friend }} </ion-item>
      </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-page>
</template>
```

Comment: That was it. 
However, in order for the list to change appropiately I had to use

Vue.set(this.Friendsdata,key,data);
this.$forceUpdate();

instead of push